# How to catch event press for unlock/lock button(physical) in background - Google Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, background-process

I writing app which features counter of unlock phone and i would like catch event press button in background. When try event press the counter has increment.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the HARDWARE_BUTTONS flutter package to do that

https://pub.dev/packages/hardware_buttons#-readme-tab- see this

you coud implement like 
    import 'dart:async';

```
import 'package:hardware_buttons/hardware_buttons.dart' as HardwareButtons;
```

double times = 0;

```
StreamSubscription<HardwareButtons.LockButtonEvent> _lockButtonSubscription;



_homeButtonSubscription = HardwareButtons.homeButtonEvents.listen((event) {
  setState(() {
    _latestHardwareButtonEvent = 'HOME_BUTTON';
    times=times+1;
  });
});

_lockButtonSubscription = HardwareButtons.lockButtonEvents.listen((event) {
  setState(() {
    _latestHardwareButtonEvent = 'LOCK_BUTTON';
  });
});


@override
void dispose() {
 super.dispose();
 _lockButtonSubscription?.cancel();
}
```